# Inner join or something else?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get 2 results into 1 html table, the results of a user being kicked/banned. A UUID is a unique code for every user.

1. The UUID is stored in BAT_players.
2. The player name is also stored in BAT_players
3. There are 3 table's: BAT_players, BAT_ban and BAT_kick

I'm trying to get the history of a user in a html table, this includes kicks and bans. Right now there are only bans in this history, i'm trying to add kicks too. This query is working fine, it shows only bans though.

```
SELECT BAT_ban.ban_staff, BAT_ban.ban_state, BAT_ban.ban_server, BAT_ban.ban_begin, BAT_ban.ban_end, BAT_ban.ban_id, BAT_kick.kick_id, BAT_ban.ban_reason, BAT_players.BAT_player, ban_soort
FROM BAT_players
INNER JOIN BAT_ban
ON BAT_ban.UUID=BAT_players.UUID
```

Unfortunately it is not working with this query, it's giving me an empty history. What am i doing wrong with the second inner join?

```
SELECT BAT_ban.ban_staff, BAT_ban.ban_state, BAT_ban.ban_server, BAT_ban.ban_begin, BAT_ban.ban_end, BAT_ban.ban_id, BAT_kick.kick_id, BAT_ban.ban_reason, BAT_players.BAT_player, ban_soort
FROM BAT_players
INNER JOIN BAT_ban
ON BAT_ban.UUID=BAT_players.UUID
INNER JOIN BAT_kick
ON BAT_kick.UUID=BAT_players.UUID ORDER BY ban_id DESC
;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? `SQL Server` or `MySQL`?

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and your desired results.  As @abl points out, you are heading for a cartesian product and that may not be what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT BAT_ban.ban_staff, BAT_ban.ban_state, BAT_ban.ban_server, BAT_ban.ban_begin, BAT_ban.ban_end, BAT_ban.ban_id, BAT_kick.kick_id, BAT_ban.ban_reason, BAT_players.BAT_player, ban_soort
FROM BAT_players LEFT JOIN 
     BAT_ban ON BAT_ban.UUID=BAT_players.UUID LEFT JOIN 
     BAT_kick ON BAT_kick.UUID=BAT_players.UUID 
ORDER BY ban_id DESC
```

To replace `NULL` values with empty strings (for `SQL Server`):

```
SELECT ISNULL(BAT_ban.ban_staff,''), ISNULL(BAT_ban.ban_state,''), ISNULL(BAT_ban.ban_server,''), ISNULL(BAT_ban.ban_begin,''), ISNULL(BAT_ban.ban_end,''), ISNULL(BAT_ban.ban_id,''), ISNULL(BAT_kick.kick_id,''), ISNULL(BAT_ban.ban_reason,''), BAT_players.BAT_player, ban_soort
FROM BAT_players LEFT JOIN 
     BAT_ban ON BAT_ban.UUID=BAT_players.UUID LEFT JOIN 
     BAT_kick ON BAT_kick.UUID=BAT_players.UUID 
ORDER BY ban_id DESC
```

For `MySQL`, replace `ISNULL` with `IFNULL`.

Comment: This will make a cartesian product of tables `BAT_ban` and `BAT_kick` so, if you have 3 bans and 7 kicks, the query will return 21 rows.

Comment: @RagingBull . . . If there are three bans (A, B, C) and seven kicks (1-7) for a given `UUID`, then that `UUID` will have 21 rows.  Your answer is technically correct; I think the question is "wrong" in that it doesn't convey what the OP really wants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's what I meant, although RagingBull is right in that it is not a cartesian product (that would be without the joins). My wrong. In my opinion, the sensible thing would be to get user "header" data, bans and kicks in three separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

An INNER JOIN *requires* a value in both tables, so if you use it for both kicks and bans, you will only see users who have been both kicked and banned.

To show users who have been either kicked *or* banned, you need to change both joins to LEFT JOIN, which essentially means "join if you can, but don't discard rows if you can't". That will include users who have been neither kicked nor banned, so you will also want an extra condition in the WHERE clause saying `BAT_ban.ban_id IS NOT NULL OR BAT_kick.kick_id IS NOT NULL`.

Note that where a user has multiple bans and multiple kicks, this will produce a row for every combination of ban and kick, since there is no rule to determine which ban should line up with which kick.

An alternative is to write two queries, each using INNER JOIN, and then combine the results. If you give them the same number and type of output columns (leaving NULL for those which aren't applicable) you can use UNION to run both and return the complete result set in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a "null" on any of your inner joins will eliminate that row from the result set.

One solution (perhaps the best solution) is to use left joins.

Another is to take the UNION of two inner joins.

Here's a great link to help visualize INNER, OUTER, LEFT and RIGHT joins:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins